# Android Service starting 2 times because of BindService and StartService

Tags: android, android-service, audio-player, android-music-player

I've been working on a music player app. I'm using a service to run the MediaPlayer. From a fragment I start the service using startService(Intent) and then I bound it to my activity. At least that's what I intend to do. The thing is that my app after getting terminated attempts to launch the service again and since the app is already terminated, the service throws an exception.

```
E/ActivityThread: Activity com.veloxigami.myapplication.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.veloxigami.myapplication.MainFragment$1@d8b488c that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.veloxigami.myapplication.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.veloxigami.myapplication.MainFragment$1@d8b488c that was originally bound here.
```

My onStartCommand() is getting called 2 times. Although I've been able to stop the crashing message by returning `START_NOT_STICKY`  in `onStartCommand()` as it was suggested in [this link](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/ebcb07). I would like to understand what is the actual problem here.

My project is available on my GitHub  if anyone would like to check the code. [Music-Player-App](https://github.com/Veloxigami/MusicPlayer).

I'm using a fragment in my MainActivity to work with the service. Below codes are where I work in between MainFragment and MediaPlayerService.

MainFragment

```
 private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
        playerService = binder.getService();
        serviceBound = true;

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Media Player Active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};


public void playAudio(int audioIndex) {
        currentFile = audioIndex;
        if (!serviceBound) {

        // storage = new DataStorage(getActivity());
       /* storage.storeAudio(playlist);
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);*/
        serviceBound = true;
        Log.v("TAG", "Creating new instance");
        Intent playerIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MediaPlayerService.class);
        getActivity().startService(playerIntent);
        getActivity().bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {

        //storage = new DataStorage(getActivity());
        /*storage.storeAudio(playlist);
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);*/

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        Log.v("TAG", "Broadcasting");
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }



    Intent playingBroadcast = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_BTN_CHANGE);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(playingBroadcast);

    Intent nextPlayingBroadcastMain = new Intent(Broadcast_SONG_TEXT_CHANGE);
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(nextPlayingBroadcastMain);
}
```

MediaPlayerService

```
private void initMediaPlayer(){
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);

    mediaPlayer.reset();



    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(currentMedia.getData());
        currentFileIndex = MainFragment.currentFile;
        MainActivity.durationText.setText(currentMedia.getDuration());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Playlist Size: "+MainFragment.playlist.size() +"\nSong No.: "+(currentFileIndex+1) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    callStateListener();

    registerAudioOutputChange();

    register_playNewAudio();

    registerStopMediaBroadcast();

    registerUpdatePlaylistReceiver();

    registerPlayButtonBroadcast();

    registerPrevButtonBroadcast();

    registerNextButtonBroadcast();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try{
        playList = new ArrayList<>();
        playList = MainFragment.playlist;
        currentMedia = MainFragment.playlist.get(MainFragment.currentFile);
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        stopSelf();
    }

    if(requestAudioFocus() == false)
        stopSelf();

    if (currentMedia.getData() != null && currentMedia.getData() !="") {
        initMediaPlayer();
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mediaPlayer!=null){
        stopMedia();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    removeAudioFocus();

    if(phoneStateListener != null){
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }


    unregisterReceiver(audioOutputChange);
    unregisterReceiver(playNewAudio);
    unregisterReceiver(stopMediaBroadcast);
    unregisterReceiver(updatePlaylistReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(playButtonBroadcast);
    unregisterReceiver(prevButtonBroadcast);
    unregisterReceiver(nextButtonBroadcast);

    //new DataStorage(getApplicationContext()).clearCachedAudioPlaylist();
}
```

Comment: Can you post both your code for MainActivity and your Service... Also services cannot be started more than once. What I mean more precisely, if your services isn't started and you call startService(...) it will only call onCreate once, and subsequent calls while it's already started will just call onStartCommand() but a new instance will not be created. Place logging statements proving such. If you see onCreate inside of your services called multiple times, onDestory() has to be getting called also.

Comment: I've added the codes for both the classes.

Comment: Place a log statement inside of your catch block of your try/catch statments in onStartCommand(), initMediaPlayer() and inside onDestory(). You wanna see if you stopSelf is getting called.

Comment: onStartCommand getting called multiple times. It will get called every single time a startService(...) is called passing an Intent for that Service. This doesn't mean the service is actually being started this many time, it simply means startService has been called several times. Only the very first call that leads to onCreate being called truly starts the Service. Calling startService multiple times to control the Service is the recommend way to communicate with a Started Service. If this bothers you, bind to the Service instead and directly call methods on the Service instance.

Comment: When I close my app then the service tries to start again. That's when this message of `leaked ServiceConnection` shows up.

`getActivity().startService(playerIntent);
        getActivity().bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`
as you can see i'm binding as well as starting service, so does this cause any problem?

Comment: You are getting that message because you never call unbindService for the MediaPlaybackService when MainActivity is being destroyed by the System and it is detecting this. How do you know the service is trying to start again? Did you add Log messages?

Comment: Problem solved. You were right. Just needed to call unbindService in onDestroy() of MainFragment.

Comment: I'll add an answer so somebody else can use this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an unbindService call anywhere in your code. So whenever the Activity gets destroyed, the system detects that it is still bound to a ServiceConnection and has been leaked. This is still the case when calling bindService inside of a Fragment. Since fragments don't inherit from Activity or Context, they don't have a context reference themselves thus they must use their parent Activities context. Remember to always call unbindService when the owning component is being destroyed, whether it's a Fragment, Activity, or even another Service. It's not unheard for a service to bind to another.

If you don't want your bound service to be destroyed when all clients unbind, you need to add special logic to determine if the Service should transition to a started service temporarily so it won't be killed by the OS, and stop the service when a client rebinds to it.